# cant get to install ipkernel on vscode through conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

**I should have everything installed, as miniconda, python and jupiter but for some reason i cannot seem to be able to install ipkernel, and it always gives me the same answer.**

**This is what it always says:**

conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- conda activate base
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

PS C:\Users\Luyen\Desktop\R data> & C:/Users/Luyen/miniconda3/python.exe c:\Users\Luyen.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:\Users\Luyen.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\shell_exec.py C:/Users/Luyen/miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe install --name base ipykernel -y C:/Users/Luyen/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp-5536kK3rtI97nWXI.log
Executing command in shell >> C:/Users/Luyen/miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe install --name base ipykernel -y
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Luyen.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\shell_exec.py", line 26, in 
subprocess.check_call(shell_args, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
File "C:\Users\Luyen\miniconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Users/Luyen/miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe', 'install', '--name', 'base', 'ipykernel', '-y']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

PS C:\Users\Luyen\Desktop\R data> & C:/Users/Luyen/miniconda3/python.exe c:\Users\Luyen.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:\Users\Luyen.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044\pythonFiles\shell_exec.py C:/Users/Luyen/miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe install --name base ipykernel -y C:/Users/Luyen/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp-5536Z87YFdwfvidb.log
Executing command in shell >> C:/Users/Luyen/miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe install --name base ipykernel -y
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

Comment: I see only the aftermath, ie error messages you are receiving. It would be a good idea to show the steps/commands you did Before the problem. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Luyen2132 -Have you tried to open the conda terminal outside VS Code and activate the conda environment? Please try to use the ["cmd" terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows) in VS Code.